# lookup with 2 values to transpose rows to columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to make it so that each Name has its own distinct row, with the subjects changed to column headers and the grade being the value, like below

[image]

I'm currently using INDEX and MATCH to look up the grades, but I have to re-write the formula every time which will be time consuming considering my actual data is a few hundred rows

Here is my formula

```
=INDEX(C2:C8,MATCH(G2&H1,A2:A8&B2:B8,0))
```

Is there a way to do this so I don't have to re-write the formula for every cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, done the first for you, needed a helper column though, see:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$8,MATCH($F2&G$1,$D$2:$D$8,)),"")
```

[image]

Added iferror() to hide missing values.

Shown the formula for cell G2 which you can drag or use control enter to enter in all cells selected.

Answer (score 1):

A non-array formula option and without helper column

Assume your "Source" table put in `A1:C8`

And, "Output" table put in `G1:J4`

In "Output" `H2`, formula copied across right to `J2`, and all copied down :

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$G2,$B:$B,H$1)
```

Then, select `H2:J4` >> `Format Cell` >> click `Accounting` >> Decimal places, choose : `0` and Symbol, choose: `None`